# nativescript activate function on dropped element

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am dragging a Label with the Pan gesture and dropping it on a Button, then i want to activate some function after the drop occurs, but I couldn't find any drop gesture/event in the native script documentation. I just need the element that the drop occurred on,
so if it is possible to get it by the drop state of the Pan gesture it will be also helpful.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I have a Label, I am trying to drag it into one of my containers, i want to listen to an event like java script onDrop so i could know when an element is dropped and on which container it has been dropped

Answer (score 1):

In NativeScript the Pan event hast `state` argument returning state number (1 === Pan gesture started, 3 === Pan gesture finished). So based on the state that the event returns  you can execute your custom logic as done [here](http://states%20=%20[%22unknown%22,%20%22start%22,%20%22change%22,%20%22end%22];)

The PAN gesture has four states as follow:

```
args.state === 0 // "unknown"
args.state === 1 // "start"
args.state === 2 // "change"
args.state === 3 // "end"
```

So the "drop" would be when args.state returns 3.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to know on which element the drop has happend?